# $QZQSMのStringでの取得方法

Tags: spresense, arduino

Arduino IDEを用いてプログラミングにチャレンジしています。v1.4.1でサンプルプログラムにより、$QZQSMをシリアルモニターに表示することができました。あとはこれをプログラム上の変数に格納して、どんなメッセージなのかを判別しようとしたのですが、$QZQSMの文字列を取得する方法がわかりませんでした。サンプルプログラムの$QZQSMを出力する部分をString qzqsmに格納してみたのですが、78と出力されました。
どなたかシリアルモニターに表示される$QZQSMの文字列を変数に格納する方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。可能でしたら、下記の表示例の9AA・・・A24を格納したいです。
表示例 $QZQSM,56,9AADF53C5680050C8AA1F5543ED2880C51022A2EF554E22AA0000012335EA24*7D

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いきなり答えを書いてしまうようで恐縮ですが、
$QZQSMのメッセージ部をデコードするための自作ライブラリと
サンプルスケッチを公開している方がいらっしゃいます。
こちらが参考になるかと思いますのでご紹介しておきます。

みちびき災危通報をデコードしてみる
https://qiita.com/baggio/items/497b654cd4ec1bfd74fc

Comment: 自作ライブラリを公開されている方がいらっしゃるとは知りませんでした。中身を勉強して私も使えるように頑張ります。いつも有益な情報をありがとうございます。